# How do microservices with independent databases communicate with each other?

Tags: microservices

For example Microservice A is having DB A and microservice B has DB B. Now Microservoce B want some share data from A. How we can handle such scenario?

Comment: It would help if you would provide more details on your exact implementation - are your microservices orchestrated? (ex. `Kubernetes`) pods or just containers? When you say `data`, do you mean files in a filesystem? Design should also consider what type of load will happen on the data. Will there be heavy reads and/or writes? Are the files huge or are they small but have thousands of them?

Comment: As both microservices A and B are having independent DB. So how my microservice B will get data from microservice A DB . Will it be some sort of Joins?

Comment: https://medium.com/slingr/what-year-did-bezos-issue-the-api-mandate-at-amazon-57f546994ca2

Answer (score 3):

Microservice B can make a synccall to get the data it needs. (like REST call) If microservice B needs this data frequently, it is good to avoid synccall to avoid network cost.

For such cases it is recommended to replicate data with an event driven architecture. With this architecture data changes in microservice A is published to a message broker like Kafka and then consumed by Microservice B. Microservice B update its own database with the information from the microservice A’s events. By that way coupling is also avoided.

Answer (score 0):

They use a communication protocol, like [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

Each Microservice needs to own its database schema and should only query its own database schema . In this case since Microservice B needs data from DB-A, Microservice A needs to expose this Data, possibly through a Rest Api and then, Microservice B needs to call that Rest Api to get the Data from DB - A